# human body measurement of height,weight and other part

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimageview, arkit

I am developing an tailor's application,and i want to measure the size of the human body for its cloth.
see in image

[image] [image] [image] [image]

after all measurement it display result like..

[image]

is this possible? i search on Google [Width and Height of Human Body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208708/width-and-height-of-human-body) and also other on SO. If any example for this type of apps really appreciated.

Comment: Idea is really good. But I am skeptical about its accuracy

Comment: its probably possible, but the question is too broad to explain here. It would probably be something similar to those facial recognisers that show where you need to place your mouth and eyes etc

Comment: It really depends on the way you keep camera and its angle. In a camera a short person can look taller etc,. I dont really think it can be done accurately.

Comment: I myself am working on such a system, and while I can't say much (because it's for a company), I will mention some issues you'll encounter: 1. The pictures you've posted are very much wishful thinking; no computer vision method I'm aware of could perform that well with such a messy background. 2. Clothing; while there are several white papers for inferring body shape under clothing, none of them are accurate enough to be practical yet. 3. Camera quality; try figuring out the theoretical accuracy you could get from the resolution of the camera. 4. Training data; you'll need a lot.

Comment: Also this is a busy area; there are many companies working on systems like this (both startups and established companies dabbling)

Comment: @Dave  don't angry. I just asked is this possible? and i Got nearby answer with my logic.

Comment: No anger here. I just know that there are too many cases of people overestimating what computer vision is capable of, so thought I'd show some issues you'll encounter. As for using multiples of head size, etc.: if it were that simple tailors would already be doing it. Without computers.

Comment: @SAMIR RATHOD I am working on similar project. have you find solution for this.

Comment: @VinayKumar nope, didn't get any solution at that time. sorry for late reply..

Comment: you should check this API : https://3dlook.me/ that's late but just what you need

Answer (score 1):

You could use the size of the head as a reference. I know that when drawing a body usually the head is used as a reference and if you want to draw a short person the height is usually 6 "heads" and for a tall person it could be up to 9 "heads".

In real life the head size can vary but they can usually be explained by things like gender, and if the app can take that into account it would reduce the error.

There are a few studies around the size of the head and how it varies (this is only after a quick google search):

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18727867
http://www.vis.caltech.edu/~graf/my_papers/proceedings/GraWic02.pdf